# How do I add values in a column with IF statements in Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```
Positions, Department, Salaries
Teacher, 600101, $1000
Janitor, 600230, $500
Principle, 600154, $1500
Secretary, 600342, $750
Manager, 600411, $2000
Teacher, 600105, $1200
Secretary, 600311, $1000
Teacher, 600300, $4000
```

I am trying to add together all of the salaries for the departments starting with 6001xx, and then also add all the salaries for departments starting 6002xx - 6004xx.

I have this and it kind of works....

```
def get_salaries(desc)
    lineAmount = df.loc[(df['Position'] == desc) & (df['Department'] < 600200) & (df['Department'] >= 600100)]['Salaries'].values[0]
    return lineAmount

totalSalaries = 0
totalSalaries += get_salaries('Teacher")
print(totalSalaries)
```

This will return only return the first salary.  If i take off the .values[0] then it will return the salaries for Teachers in the correct department but it returns all of them in one output with the index as well, and it will not add them together. I need to be able to add the $1,000 and $1,200 from the teachers salaries from departments starting with 6001xx, and I just cannot figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the complete error or output (edit the question to show it as properly formatted text)?

Comment: Sorry, I have been trying so many different things. I do not get an error with the above code but it is still not correct. When i have the .values[0] at the end i only get the first salary number ($1000).  When i take off the .values[0] i get a 2 line output that includes the index and salary number with the following under.  Name: Salaries, dtype: float64.

Comment: Remove the `.values[0]` then you have a pandas series which supports a method [`sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas.Series.sum).

Comment: Ok, i will look into Sum() panda series. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new column as department_id for each of 60001xx, 6002xx and then use groupby:

```
df['department_id']=np.floor(df['Department']/100)

df.groupby(['department_id'])['Salaries'].sum()
```